# Alternate between 3 threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have 3 threads doing independent tasks. I am trying to emulate *context switching* i.e `I want the first thread to pause its execution and run the 3rd thread and then after some time want the 3rd thread to pause its execution and run the 2nd thread and so on`.

I have the following code currently:

```
if ((result = pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL)) != 0) {
        perror("Error initializing mutex.");
}

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, run_process,
                            (void *) processes[i]);
    }
}
```

run_process:

```
void* run_process(void * process_data) {

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    Process pdata = (Process *) process_data;
    int result;

    printf("Job %d started.\n", order);

    // do some work
    // the mutex lock makes sure only one thread is here at a time
    for (i = 0; i < (0xFFFFFFFF); i++);

    printf("Job %d finished.\n", order);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

The processes will work and run independently without interruptions by other threads. Now I want to implement a context switcher, which would pause and switch from thread1 to thread2 while thread1 is doing its "work" and then come back to thread1 and resume its execution.

I am a total novice about threading and have no clue how would I go about implementing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to *emulate* threads, then you could just write a single-threaded program.

Comment: I wanna emulate context switching in threads, like a scheduler would do.

Comment: Then ask the OS to restrict your process to run on a single core (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity). AFAICT pthread is the wrong tool for the job anyway, because it's meant to abstract native threads (i.e. those managed by a native scheduler), not to implement userland scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pthread_cond_wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html), which will allow a thread to sleep and [pthread_cond_signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_signal.html) to wake a specific thread.

Thread 1 waits:

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 ) ;

pthread_mutex_wait( &cond1 , &mutex1 ) ;

pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 ) ;
```

Thread 2 signals thread 1 to continue:

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 ) ;

pthread_mutex_signal( &cond1 ) ;

pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 ) ;
```

You will need a shared mutex and a conditional per thread, if you want any thread to wake any other.

Answer (score 0):

To do something similar to what you did above but where the main thread is the scheduling thread, you could possibly use semaphores [link](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview). You can have each thread wait on its semaphore on startup. When the main thread then wants to run a thread, it post to the given threads semaphore, activating the given thread.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to to is to simulate what happens with thread scheduling on a uniprocessor machine, the easiest way is to use the OS [processor affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) APIs to have your process run on a single core.

Answer (score 0):

pthreads (probably with the help of your OS kernel) is already doing what you are trying to do.

When you spawn multiple threads, the switching of execution context between those threads is handled by pthreads. In most implementations that I know of, pthreads uses the facilities provided by the kernel to  do this, but either way your program does not need to worry about it.

The scheduler will automatically switch contexts, and will likely use multiple CPU cores in your machine to execute some or all of the simultaneously.

What your program does have to do is handle the interaction between the threads, and between the threads and any shared data structures. Facilities such as mutexes, conditional wait variables, etc are used for this.

If you are trying to implement your own scheduler, perhaps as part of a homework assignment or a learning exercise, then you will need to start by not using pthreads at all. If that is the case you might like to consult [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145321/implementing-a-user-level-threads-package).